# from two lists to one by binding elements

Tags: r, list, lapply, rbind

I have two lists with two elements each,

```
l1 <- list(data.table(id=1:5, group=1), data.table(id=1:5, group=1))
l2 <- list(data.table(id=1:5, group=2), data.table(id=1:5, group=2))
```

and I would like to `rbind(.)` both elements, resulting in a new list with two elements.

```
> l
[[1]]
    id group
 1:  1     1
 2:  2     1
 3:  3     1
 4:  4     1
 5:  5     1
 6:  1     2
 7:  2     2
 8:  3     2
 9:  4     2
10:  5     2

[[2]]
    id group
 1:  1     1
 2:  2     1
 3:  3     1
 4:  4     1
 5:  5     1
 6:  1     2
 7:  2     2
 8:  3     2
 9:  4     2
10:  5     2
```

However, I only find examples where `rbind(.)` is applied to bind across elements. I suspect that the solution lies somewhere in `lapply(.)` but `lapply(c(l1,l2),rbind)` appears to bind the lists, producing a list of four elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `mapply` or `Map`. `mapply` (which stands for multivariate apply) applies the supplied function to the first elements of the arguments and then the second and then the third and so on. `Map` is quite literally a wrapper to `mapply` that does not try to simplify the result (try running mapply with and without SIMPLIFY=T). Shorter, arguments are recycled as necessary.

```
mapply(x=l1, y=l2, function(x,y) rbind(x,y), SIMPLIFY = F)
#[[1]]
#    id group
# 1:  1     1
# 2:  2     1
# 3:  3     1
# 4:  4     1
# 5:  5     1
# 6:  1     2
# 7:  2     2
# 8:  3     2
# 9:  4     2
#10:  5     2
#
#[[2]]
#    id group
# 1:  1     1
# 2:  2     1
# 3:  3     1
# 4:  4     1
# 5:  5     1
# 6:  1     2
# 7:  2     2
# 8:  3     2
# 9:  4     2
#10:  5     2
```

As @Parfait pointed out you can do this `Map`:

```
Map(rbind, l1, l2)
#[[1]]
#    id group
# 1:  1     1
# 2:  2     1
# 3:  3     1
# 4:  4     1
# 5:  5     1
# 6:  1     2
# 7:  2     2
# 8:  3     2
# 9:  4     2
#10:  5     2
#
#[[2]]
#    id group
# 1:  1     1
# 2:  2     1
# 3:  3     1
# 4:  4     1
# 5:  5     1
# 6:  1     2
# 7:  2     2
# 8:  3     2
# 9:  4     2
#10:  5     2
```

Comment: And `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` is simply `Map`!

Comment: BTW - We should quickly describe `mapply` for OP and future readers (avoiding code-only answers). Something like "elementwise loop between two or more equal length lists".

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse0
map2(l1, l2, bind_rows)
```